# How to add onClick actions to calendar events using Django-Scheduler?

Tags: python, django, django-scheduler

I'm using [Django-scheduler](https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler) in my project. I really like the calendar and the ability to create recurring events.

After installing it the the only code (besides stuff in settings.py) I've added is to `myproject/urls.py`:

```
url(r'^schedule/', include('schedule.urls')),
```

I then created a calendar called testcalendar and an event called Test Event in /admin. I then traversed to http://127.0.0.1:8000/schedule/calendar/month/testcalendar/. And woo who! - I see the event and my calendar. The template it uses is `schedule/calendar_by_period.html` which extends base.html - which is also nice. I can move forward and backward in months and select alternate calendar views (tri-month, year, etc)...nice!

[image]

I've gotten all of this functionality by simply adding that single line in `urls.py` but I don't think I can get away with that any more. I can't understand if the [documentation](https://django-scheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) explains how to incorporate it further into an existing project.

**Specifically**, I want to add an action when the user clicks on the test event (see screenshot). The only way I can do this now is by modifying the source code to add some jQuery in `schedule/calendar_by_period.html`. But adding JQuery there or in base.html to catch the calendar event would be pretty tricky anyway since the div and button generated for calendar events don't have unique ids or classes. Plus I doubt that's the intention of the creators.

Do I create custom url paths that point to my own view that inherits from CalendarByPeriodsView? If so I still don't have access to the template. Do I just copy and paste the template and add it locally to my project templates? That seems wrong too.

Comment: Did you every find an answer?  I'm running into the same issues

Comment: I think so- but it was so long ago and I can't look it up right now. There is hope I think but I can't help right now.